# Query for pagination on the SQL side

Tags: mysql

How can I implement custom pagination in mysql using a query? Based on the page number I need to fetch the records from the database, is it possible? It would be helpful to get some queries for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 0,10
```

To display your pagination you also need to know the total of rows in order to calculate the number of page links to display like:

Page: 1 2 3 4 5 6 ….

Making a query to MySQL to count the number of rows like “SELECT COUNT(*) …” is not an option, you would lose some of the performance you saved with the “LIMIT” query in the first place. There’s a much more efficient way of doing this, you just need to modify your original query just a little, like:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM items LIMIT 0,10');
```

Immediately after that first query you run:

```
$countData = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT found_rows() AS total'));
$totRows = $countData['total'];
```

Comment: if i am not sorting my results, then is it keep order?if i pass limit 0,10 and next time limit 10,20 ,is it correctly displays the next 10 rows or it take random rows?

Comment: if you pass limit 10,20 then it fatch the record from 10 to 20

Answer (score 1):

Through PHP you need:

**$PageSize** - means how many rows you want to dispaly.
**$Pageoffset** - means (CurrentPageNo * PageSize)

```
     $query =" select * from table limit $Pageoffset, $PageSize';
     // limit restricts the no. of rows fetching.
```

Like wise you can do in mysql.

Comment: if i am not sorting my results, then is it keep order?if i pass limit 0,10 and next time limit 10,20 ,is it correctly displays the next 10 rows or it take random rows?

Comment: it will keep in order as it is been displayed in table.

Answer (score 1):

- [See MySQL LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

example,

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

will display 10 records starting from the first record.

Comment: if i am not sorting my results, then is it keep order?if i pass limit 0,10 and next time limit 10,20 ,is it correctly displays the next 10 rows or it take random rows?

Comment: it should be `0, 10`, `10, 10`, `30, 10`,... if you want to get 10 rows per page. and it doesn't take random rows.